# "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:" when installing UWSGI in a conda environment, mac

Tags: python, pip, uwsgi, pypi

I'm trying to install uwsgi using pip on my computer in a conda environment, but I keep getting the same error message over and over again(check below). I even tried a [workaround mentioned here](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/2232#issuecomment-833880892), I tried changing environments but none of it worked. Can someone help explain to me why I'm getting this error and how I can solve it? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/faisalalbasu/opt/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/4m/_ds9pd454c98d4njtmqynykh0000gn/T/pip-install-nrj73hcf/uwsgi_3dfc65897ef14fbca5cf7621e0da26cc/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/4m/_ds9pd454c98d4njtmqynykh0000gn/T/pip-install-nrj73hcf/uwsgi_3dfc65897ef14fbca5cf7621e0da26cc/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/4m/_ds9pd454c98d4njtmqynykh0000gn/T/pip-wheel-1ac013p7
       cwd: /private/var/folders/4m/_ds9pd454c98d4njtmqynykh0000gn/T/pip-install-nrj73hcf/uwsgi_3dfc65897ef14fbca5cf7621e0da26cc/
  Complete output (168 lines):
  /Users/faisalalbasu/opt/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'descriptions'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  copying uwsgidecorators.py -> build/lib
  /Users/faisalalbasu/opt/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
    warnings.warn(
  installing to build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/wheel
  running install
  using profile: buildconf/default.ini
  detected include path: ['/usr/local/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks']
  Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
  detected CPU cores: 4
  configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_OSX_SPINLOCK -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_KQUEUE -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.45/include -DUWSGI_PCRE -DUWSGI_ROUTING -DUWSGI_UUID -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.20\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="20" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -DUWSGI_XML -DUWSGI_XML_EXPAT -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);" -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
  *** uWSGI compiling server core ***
  [thread 0][clang] core/utils.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/protocol.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/socket.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/logging.o
  core/utils.c:3676:6: warning: variable 'pos' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
          int pos = 0;
              ^
  1 warning generated.
  [thread 0][clang] core/master.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/master_utils.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/emperor.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/notify.o
  [thread 0][clang] core/mule.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/subscription.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/stats.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/sendfile.o
  [thread 0][clang] core/async.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/master_checks.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/fifo.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/offload.o
  [thread 0][clang] core/io.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/static.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/websockets.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/spooler.o
  [thread 0][clang] core/snmp.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/exceptions.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/config.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/setup_utils.o
  [thread 0][clang] core/clock.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/init.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/buffer.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/reader.o
  [thread 0][clang] core/writer.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/alarm.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/cron.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/hooks.o
  [thread 0][clang] core/plugins.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/lock.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/cache.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/daemons.o
  [thread 0][clang] core/errors.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/hash.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/master_events.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/chunked.o
  [thread 0][clang] core/queue.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/event.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/signal.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/strings.o
  [thread 0][clang] core/progress.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/timebomb.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/ini.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/fsmon.o
  [thread 0][clang] core/mount.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/metrics.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/plugins_builder.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/sharedarea.o
  core/mount.c:112:16: warning: variable 'mountflags' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
          unsigned long mountflags = 0;
                        ^
  core/mount.c:150:16: warning: variable 'mountflags' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
          unsigned long mountflags = 0;
                        ^
  2 warnings generated.
  [thread 0][clang] core/rpc.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/gateway.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/loop.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/cookie.o
  [thread 0][clang] core/querystring.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/rb_timers.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/transformations.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/uwsgi.o
  [thread 0][clang] proto/base.o
  [thread 2][clang] proto/uwsgi.o
  [thread 1][clang] proto/http.o
  [thread 3][clang] proto/fastcgi.o
  [thread 0][clang] proto/scgi.o
  [thread 2][clang] proto/puwsgi.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/zlib.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/regexp.o
  [thread 0][clang] core/routing.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/yaml.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/xmlconf.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/dot_h.o
  [thread 0][clang] core/config_py.o
  *** uWSGI compiling embedded plugins ***
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/python/python_plugin.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/python/pyutils.o
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/python/pyloader.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/python/pump_subhandler.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/python/gil.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.o
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/python/profiler.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/python/symimporter.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/python/tracebacker.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/python/raw.o
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/gevent/gevent.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/gevent/hooks.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/ping/ping_plugin.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/cache/cache.o
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/nagios/nagios.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/rrdtool/rrdtool.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/carbon/carbon.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/rpc/rpc_plugin.o
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/corerouter/cr_common.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/corerouter/cr_map.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/corerouter/corerouter.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/fastrouter/fastrouter.o
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/http/http.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/http/keepalive.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/http/https.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/http/spdy3.o
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/signal/signal_plugin.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/syslog/syslog_plugin.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/rsyslog/rsyslog_plugin.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/logsocket/logsocket_plugin.o
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/router_uwsgi/router_uwsgi.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/router_redirect/router_redirect.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/router_basicauth/router_basicauth.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/zergpool/zergpool.o
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/redislog/redislog_plugin.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/mongodblog/mongodblog_plugin.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/router_rewrite/router_rewrite.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/router_http/router_http.o
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/logfile/logfile.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/router_cache/router_cache.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/rawrouter/rawrouter.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/router_static/router_static.o
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/sslrouter/sslrouter.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/spooler/spooler_plugin.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/cheaper_busyness/cheaper_busyness.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/symcall/symcall_plugin.o
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/transformation_tofile/tofile.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/transformation_gzip/gzip.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/transformation_chunked/chunked.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/transformation_offload/offload.o
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/router_memcached/router_memcached.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/router_redis/router_redis.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/router_hash/router_hash.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/router_expires/expires.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/router_metrics/plugin.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/transformation_template/tt.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o
  *** uWSGI linking ***
  clang -o build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/wheel/uWSGI-2.0.20.data/scripts/uwsgi  core/utils.o core/protocol.o core/socket.o core/logging.o core/master.o core/master_utils.o core/emperor.o core/notify.o core/mule.o core/subscription.o core/stats.o core/sendfile.o core/async.o core/master_checks.o core/fifo.o core/offload.o core/io.o core/static.o core/websockets.o core/spooler.o core/snmp.o core/exceptions.o core/config.o core/setup_utils.o core/clock.o core/init.o core/buffer.o core/reader.o core/writer.o core/alarm.o core/cron.o core/hooks.o core/plugins.o core/lock.o core/cache.o core/daemons.o core/errors.o core/hash.o core/master_events.o core/chunked.o core/queue.o core/event.o core/signal.o core/strings.o core/progress.o core/timebomb.o core/ini.o core/fsmon.o core/mount.o core/metrics.o core/plugins_builder.o core/sharedarea.o core/rpc.o core/gateway.o core/loop.o core/cookie.o core/querystring.o core/rb_timers.o core/transformations.o core/uwsgi.o proto/base.o proto/uwsgi.o proto/http.o proto/fastcgi.o proto/scgi.o proto/puwsgi.o core/zlib.o core/regexp.o core/routing.o core/yaml.o core/xmlconf.o core/dot_h.o core/config_py.o plugins/python/python_plugin.o plugins/python/pyutils.o plugins/python/pyloader.o plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o plugins/python/pump_subhandler.o plugins/python/gil.o plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.o plugins/python/profiler.o plugins/python/symimporter.o plugins/python/tracebacker.o plugins/python/raw.o plugins/gevent/gevent.o plugins/gevent/hooks.o plugins/ping/ping_plugin.o plugins/cache/cache.o plugins/nagios/nagios.o plugins/rrdtool/rrdtool.o plugins/carbon/carbon.o plugins/rpc/rpc_plugin.o plugins/corerouter/cr_common.o plugins/corerouter/cr_map.o plugins/corerouter/corerouter.o plugins/fastrouter/fastrouter.o plugins/http/http.o plugins/http/keepalive.o plugins/http/https.o plugins/http/spdy3.o plugins/signal/signal_plugin.o plugins/syslog/syslog_plugin.o plugins/rsyslog/rsyslog_plugin.o plugins/logsocket/logsocket_plugin.o plugins/router_uwsgi/router_uwsgi.o plugins/router_redirect/router_redirect.o plugins/router_basicauth/router_basicauth.o plugins/zergpool/zergpool.o plugins/redislog/redislog_plugin.o plugins/mongodblog/mongodblog_plugin.o plugins/router_rewrite/router_rewrite.o plugins/router_http/router_http.o plugins/logfile/logfile.o plugins/router_cache/router_cache.o plugins/rawrouter/rawrouter.o plugins/router_static/router_static.o plugins/sslrouter/sslrouter.o plugins/spooler/spooler_plugin.o plugins/cheaper_busyness/cheaper_busyness.o plugins/symcall/symcall_plugin.o plugins/transformation_tofile/tofile.o plugins/transformation_gzip/gzip.o plugins/transformation_chunked/chunked.o plugins/transformation_offload/offload.o plugins/router_memcached/router_memcached.o plugins/router_redis/router_redis.o plugins/router_hash/router_hash.o plugins/router_expires/expires.o plugins/router_metrics/plugin.o plugins/transformation_template/tt.o plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o -lpthread -lm -lz -L/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.45/lib -lpcre -lexpat -ldl -framework CoreFoundation /Users/faisalalbasu/opt/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/lib/python3.10/config-3.10-darwin/libpython3.10.a
  clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/faisalalbasu/opt/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/lib/python3.10/config-3.10-darwin/libpython3.10.a'
  *** error linking uWSGI ***
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for uwsgi
  Running setup.py clean for uwsgi
Failed to build uwsgi
Installing collected packages: uwsgi
    Running setup.py install for uwsgi ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/faisalalbasu/opt/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/4m/_ds9pd454c98d4njtmqynykh0000gn/T/pip-install-nrj73hcf/uwsgi_3dfc65897ef14fbca5cf7621e0da26cc/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/4m/_ds9pd454c98d4njtmqynykh0000gn/T/pip-install-nrj73hcf/uwsgi_3dfc65897ef14fbca5cf7621e0da26cc/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/4m/_ds9pd454c98d4njtmqynykh0000gn/T/pip-record-9cbr9in8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/faisalalbasu/opt/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/include/python3.10/uwsgi
         cwd: /private/var/folders/4m/_ds9pd454c98d4njtmqynykh0000gn/T/pip-install-nrj73hcf/uwsgi_3dfc65897ef14fbca5cf7621e0da26cc/
    Complete output (150 lines):
    /Users/faisalalbasu/opt/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'descriptions'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    /Users/faisalalbasu/opt/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    using profile: buildconf/default.ini
    detected include path: ['/usr/local/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks']
    Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
    detected CPU cores: 4
    configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_OSX_SPINLOCK -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_KQUEUE -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.45/include -DUWSGI_PCRE -DUWSGI_ROUTING -DUWSGI_UUID -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.20\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="20" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -DUWSGI_XML -DUWSGI_XML_EXPAT -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);" -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
    *** uWSGI compiling server core ***
    core/utils.o is up to date
    core/protocol.o is up to date
    core/socket.o is up to date
    core/logging.o is up to date
    core/master.o is up to date
    core/master_utils.o is up to date
    core/emperor.o is up to date
    core/notify.o is up to date
    core/mule.o is up to date
    core/subscription.o is up to date
    core/stats.o is up to date
    core/sendfile.o is up to date
    core/async.o is up to date
    core/master_checks.o is up to date
    core/fifo.o is up to date
    core/offload.o is up to date
    core/io.o is up to date
    core/static.o is up to date
    core/websockets.o is up to date
    core/spooler.o is up to date
    core/snmp.o is up to date
    core/exceptions.o is up to date
    core/config.o is up to date
    core/setup_utils.o is up to date
    core/clock.o is up to date
    core/init.o is up to date
    core/buffer.o is up to date
    core/reader.o is up to date
    core/writer.o is up to date
    core/alarm.o is up to date
    core/cron.o is up to date
    core/hooks.o is up to date
    core/plugins.o is up to date
    core/lock.o is up to date
    core/cache.o is up to date
    core/daemons.o is up to date
    core/errors.o is up to date
    core/hash.o is up to date
    core/master_events.o is up to date
    core/chunked.o is up to date
    core/queue.o is up to date
    core/event.o is up to date
    core/signal.o is up to date
    core/strings.o is up to date
    core/progress.o is up to date
    core/timebomb.o is up to date
    core/ini.o is up to date
    core/fsmon.o is up to date
    core/mount.o is up to date
    core/metrics.o is up to date
    core/plugins_builder.o is up to date
    core/sharedarea.o is up to date
    core/rpc.o is up to date
    core/gateway.o is up to date
    core/loop.o is up to date
    core/cookie.o is up to date
    core/querystring.o is up to date
    core/rb_timers.o is up to date
    core/transformations.o is up to date
    core/uwsgi.o is up to date
    proto/base.o is up to date
    proto/uwsgi.o is up to date
    proto/http.o is up to date
    proto/fastcgi.o is up to date
    proto/scgi.o is up to date
    proto/puwsgi.o is up to date
    core/zlib.o is up to date
    core/regexp.o is up to date
    core/routing.o is up to date
    core/yaml.o is up to date
    core/xmlconf.o is up to date
    [thread 1][clang] core/dot_h.o
    [thread 2][clang] core/config_py.o
    *** uWSGI compiling embedded plugins ***
    plugins/python/python_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/python/pyutils.o is up to date
    plugins/python/pyloader.o is up to date
    plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o is up to date
    plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o is up to date
    plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o is up to date
    plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o is up to date
    plugins/python/pump_subhandler.o is up to date
    plugins/python/gil.o is up to date
    plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.o is up to date
    plugins/python/profiler.o is up to date
    plugins/python/symimporter.o is up to date
    plugins/python/tracebacker.o is up to date
    plugins/python/raw.o is up to date
    plugins/gevent/gevent.o is up to date
    plugins/gevent/hooks.o is up to date
    plugins/ping/ping_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/cache/cache.o is up to date
    plugins/nagios/nagios.o is up to date
    plugins/rrdtool/rrdtool.o is up to date
    plugins/carbon/carbon.o is up to date
    plugins/rpc/rpc_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/corerouter/cr_common.o is up to date
    plugins/corerouter/cr_map.o is up to date
    plugins/corerouter/corerouter.o is up to date
    plugins/fastrouter/fastrouter.o is up to date
    plugins/http/http.o is up to date
    plugins/http/keepalive.o is up to date
    plugins/http/https.o is up to date
    plugins/http/spdy3.o is up to date
    plugins/signal/signal_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/syslog/syslog_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/rsyslog/rsyslog_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/logsocket/logsocket_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/router_uwsgi/router_uwsgi.o is up to date
    plugins/router_redirect/router_redirect.o is up to date
    plugins/router_basicauth/router_basicauth.o is up to date
    plugins/zergpool/zergpool.o is up to date
    plugins/redislog/redislog_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/mongodblog/mongodblog_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/router_rewrite/router_rewrite.o is up to date
    plugins/router_http/router_http.o is up to date
    plugins/logfile/logfile.o is up to date
    plugins/router_cache/router_cache.o is up to date
    plugins/rawrouter/rawrouter.o is up to date
    plugins/router_static/router_static.o is up to date
    plugins/sslrouter/sslrouter.o is up to date
    plugins/spooler/spooler_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/cheaper_busyness/cheaper_busyness.o is up to date
    plugins/symcall/symcall_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/transformation_tofile/tofile.o is up to date
    plugins/transformation_gzip/gzip.o is up to date
    plugins/transformation_chunked/chunked.o is up to date
    plugins/transformation_offload/offload.o is up to date
    plugins/router_memcached/router_memcached.o is up to date
    plugins/router_redis/router_redis.o is up to date
    plugins/router_hash/router_hash.o is up to date
    plugins/router_expires/expires.o is up to date
    plugins/router_metrics/plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/transformation_template/tt.o is up to date
    plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o is up to date
    *** uWSGI linking ***
    clang -o /Users/faisalalbasu/opt/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/bin/uwsgi  core/utils.o core/protocol.o core/socket.o core/logging.o core/master.o core/master_utils.o core/emperor.o core/notify.o core/mule.o core/subscription.o core/stats.o core/sendfile.o core/async.o core/master_checks.o core/fifo.o core/offload.o core/io.o core/static.o core/websockets.o core/spooler.o core/snmp.o core/exceptions.o core/config.o core/setup_utils.o core/clock.o core/init.o core/buffer.o core/reader.o core/writer.o core/alarm.o core/cron.o core/hooks.o core/plugins.o core/lock.o core/cache.o core/daemons.o core/errors.o core/hash.o core/master_events.o core/chunked.o core/queue.o core/event.o core/signal.o core/strings.o core/progress.o core/timebomb.o core/ini.o core/fsmon.o core/mount.o core/metrics.o core/plugins_builder.o core/sharedarea.o core/rpc.o core/gateway.o core/loop.o core/cookie.o core/querystring.o core/rb_timers.o core/transformations.o core/uwsgi.o proto/base.o proto/uwsgi.o proto/http.o proto/fastcgi.o proto/scgi.o proto/puwsgi.o core/zlib.o core/regexp.o core/routing.o core/yaml.o core/xmlconf.o core/dot_h.o core/config_py.o plugins/python/python_plugin.o plugins/python/pyutils.o plugins/python/pyloader.o plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o plugins/python/pump_subhandler.o plugins/python/gil.o plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.o plugins/python/profiler.o plugins/python/symimporter.o plugins/python/tracebacker.o plugins/python/raw.o plugins/gevent/gevent.o plugins/gevent/hooks.o plugins/ping/ping_plugin.o plugins/cache/cache.o plugins/nagios/nagios.o plugins/rrdtool/rrdtool.o plugins/carbon/carbon.o plugins/rpc/rpc_plugin.o plugins/corerouter/cr_common.o plugins/corerouter/cr_map.o plugins/corerouter/corerouter.o plugins/fastrouter/fastrouter.o plugins/http/http.o plugins/http/keepalive.o plugins/http/https.o plugins/http/spdy3.o plugins/signal/signal_plugin.o plugins/syslog/syslog_plugin.o plugins/rsyslog/rsyslog_plugin.o plugins/logsocket/logsocket_plugin.o plugins/router_uwsgi/router_uwsgi.o plugins/router_redirect/router_redirect.o plugins/router_basicauth/router_basicauth.o plugins/zergpool/zergpool.o plugins/redislog/redislog_plugin.o plugins/mongodblog/mongodblog_plugin.o plugins/router_rewrite/router_rewrite.o plugins/router_http/router_http.o plugins/logfile/logfile.o plugins/router_cache/router_cache.o plugins/rawrouter/rawrouter.o plugins/router_static/router_static.o plugins/sslrouter/sslrouter.o plugins/spooler/spooler_plugin.o plugins/cheaper_busyness/cheaper_busyness.o plugins/symcall/symcall_plugin.o plugins/transformation_tofile/tofile.o plugins/transformation_gzip/gzip.o plugins/transformation_chunked/chunked.o plugins/transformation_offload/offload.o plugins/router_memcached/router_memcached.o plugins/router_redis/router_redis.o plugins/router_hash/router_hash.o plugins/router_expires/expires.o plugins/router_metrics/plugin.o plugins/transformation_template/tt.o plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o -lpthread -lm -lz -L/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.45/lib -lpcre -lexpat -ldl -framework CoreFoundation /Users/faisalalbasu/opt/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/lib/python3.10/config-3.10-darwin/libpython3.10.a
    clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/faisalalbasu/opt/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/lib/python3.10/config-3.10-darwin/libpython3.10.a'
    *** error linking uWSGI ***
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/faisalalbasu/opt/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/4m/_ds9pd454c98d4njtmqynykh0000gn/T/pip-install-nrj73hcf/uwsgi_3dfc65897ef14fbca5cf7621e0da26cc/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/4m/_ds9pd454c98d4njtmqynykh0000gn/T/pip-install-nrj73hcf/uwsgi_3dfc65897ef14fbca5cf7621e0da26cc/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/4m/_ds9pd454c98d4njtmqynykh0000gn/T/pip-record-9cbr9in8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/faisalalbasu/opt/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/include/python3.10/uwsgi Check the logs for full command output.


  [1]: https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/2232#issuecomment-833880892
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a workaround using conda forge  https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/uwsgi.

I first tried installing it using `conda install -c conda-forge uwsgi` and got an error:

```
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                     

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

- uwsgi -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|3.4.*']
- uwsgi -> python[version='3.7.*|3.8.*|3.9.*']

Your python: python=3.10

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

So I tried downgrading python and installing it again using pip, it still didn't work with pip but when I used the conda forge install again it worked.